# mainWindow is not defined electron js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I was making an app in **ElectronJS**, and tried to load a different html document on a event. But when I tried to do this, I go this error (see in the image below)

[image: The error mesage]

So, have I done anything wrong, or is there a different way of doing this..?

Here is my code:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')

const path = require('path');

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    icon: "icon.png",
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  mainWindow.loadFile("index.html");

}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow()

    app.on('activate', function () {
        if(BrowserWindow.getAllWindows.length === 0) createWindow()
    })
}).catch(err => console.log(err))

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    if(process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

ipcMain.on("login", (event, data) => {
    Authenticator.getAuth(data.u, data.p).then(() => {
        event.sender.send('done')
      
        mainWindow.loadURL(path.join(__dirname, "home.html"))
    }).catch((err) => {
        event.sender.send("err", { er: err })
    })
})
```

Comment: You might want to try something simpler then an Electron application if your JS skills are the stage where you are struggling with basic variable scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined it in `createWindow`; it isn't accessible outside of that function.

So return it, and then capture it when you call `createWindow`:

```
function createWindow () {
  // ...
  return mainWindow;
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    const mainWindow = createWindow()
```

Comment: Honestly speaking I do not think this would be the best case scenario in this case. As I can see author is working with electron ipc. So I would recommend using something like
`mainWindow = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();`

Otherwise you would just reload/recreate your window each time.